# Why won't this simple raster layer in my mapfile show up?

Tags: raster, mapserver

I am trying to get a simple raster layer to work on MapServer. I am not exactly going to be using geographic data, but I want to "georeference" multiple rasters together to create a map-like interface. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get over this initial step of getting a single raster to show up using my mapfile.

Mapfile:

```
MAP
    IMAGETYPE   PNG
    EXTENT      -180 -90 180 90
    SIZE        400 300
    IMAGECOLOR  255 255 255
    UNITS       DD
    STATUS      ON
    DEBUG       ON


    LAYER
        NAME    "base"
        DATA    "Base.png"
        STATUS  ON
        TYPE    RASTER
    END 
END
```

My directory structure is like this:

/home/username/public_html/cgi-bin/mapserv.cgi

/home/username/public_html/dir/Base.png

/home/username/public_html/dir/mapfile.map

/home/username/public_html/dir/tmp/

When I visit the map using something like the following link, all i get is a blank image of the correct size but not the actual Base.png image. No pink tiles. No error message. What am I doing wrong?

*http://myurl.com/cgi-bin/mapserv.cgi?map=/home/username/public_html/dir/mapfile.map&layer=base&mode=map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing the "SHAPEPATH" tag, that actually is needed to tell mapserver where all the data resides.